# iOS/iPhone :UIView not adding elements for NSMutableArray (containing UILabel objects)

Tags: uiview, nsmutablearray, uilabel

I have a **UIView** in which i have written the following method:

```
- (void)drawLabels:(NSMutableArray*)labelArray{
  for (int i=0; i<[labelArray count]; i++) {        
    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
    labelFrame = CGRectInset(labelFrame, 5, 5);
    UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[labelArray objectAtIndex:i];
    [self addSubview:label];
```

}

The code crashes with the following error :

> -[UIDeviceRGBColor superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e397c0
>   2012-11-27 18:37:33.559 QuartzSample[57621:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIDeviceRGBColor superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e397c0'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x13cf022 0x1560cd6 0x13d0cbd 0x1335ed0 0x1335cb2 0x55e4f 0x5014b 0x4398 0x38a1 0xe0a1e 0x3f401 0x3f670 0x3f836 0x4672a 0x292b 0x17386 0x18274 0x27183 0x27c38 0x1b634 0x12b9ef5 0x13a3195 0x1307ff2 0x13068da 0x1305d84 0x1305c9b 0x17c65 0x19626 0x2632 0x25a5)
>   terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

I wish to place the labels on the view with all the formatting(color, font,size,etc.).
Also when i put the following code :

```
NSLog(@"%@",[labelArray objectAtIndex:i]);
```

i get the following in console:
  **UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 1 0 0.3**

Can anybody elaborate ?

Comment: The error message says that you are calling "superview" on a color. I guess you thought it was a view. Check for the code that does that. Maybe that array did not contain UILabel objects after all?

Comment: Ok.. i will check , then what is th final solution. can u provide some code @Thilo

Comment: The problem looks as if it has something to do with the objects inside `labelArray`.  Can you update the question to show how those are created and how the array is populated?

Comment: `UILabel *l1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    l1.text=@"Text 1";
    
    UILabel *l2 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    l2.text=@"Text 2";
    
    UILabel *l3 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    l3.text=@"Text 3";
    
    labels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:l1,l2,l3, nil];
`

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems you are settings `labelFrame` but you are not using it.
2. Before using addSubView, ensure `label` is not `nil`
3. To configure the font and size of a `UILabel` use `setFont:` method passing a `UIFont` as parameter
4. To configure the color use `.textColor` property passing a `UIColor` as parameter